# Can't run ng serve because of bootstrap?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-bootstrap

I have a strange problem with Angular and none of my research was very useful.

I'm really new to this and started a little project where I added bootstrap to my Angular project. I followed a procedure ([this one](https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/#2-installing-bootstrap-from-npm)) and it worked well!

But today I tried to run the `npm serve` command and had the following error : [Terminal Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNkUV.png)

I don't really get what's the error but found that the `agular-cli.json` file could be the key so here it is the important part.

```html
  "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
```

I tried to replace the `styles.css` by `src/styles.css` but it didn't work.

The worst part is that it worked 2 or 3 days ago and I didn't do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bootstrap styles path is wrong. Your `styles` entry should be:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
]
```

Comment: Indeed it works !
However I don't get why because the angular-cli.json file is at the same level that the node_modules in my project structure....

Comment: Because we tell the angular cli that our root folder is `src` which is one level deeper than `node_modules`